# JSF query string parameters

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, cdi, weld

I've probably completely missed something foundational here coming from a classic ASP world, but I'm completely new to JSF and Java. I can't seem to be able to append a query string to my initial page request without it generating an error.

If I type `http://localhost:8080/fooBean` in my browser there's no error, however, if I use `http://localhost:8080/fooBean/index.xhtml?param1=value&param2=value2` it generates the following error:

> WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScope

```
@Named(value = "fooBean")
@SessionScoped
public class fooBean implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: No sure if it can cause problems, but in Java you should always start a class name by a uppercase ie : fooBean > FooBean.

Comment: Are you referencing 'fooBean' as an expression? Is there a #{fooBesn} in your code somewhere? Also what is /fooBean in your URL mapped to? Normally an @Named does not automatically map a bean to a URL pattern (I assume this is just the name of your app). Can you show the index.xhtml code?

Comment: Also, in your `web.xml` are you mapping `FacesServlet`? What Container are you using?

Comment: John, I'm sorry, I feel really overwhelmed by all of the new Java terminology.  I'm not sure what to look for to know what "Container" I'm using.  Are you referring to the /faces/* component?

Comment: Index.xhtml - <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        #{fooBean.makeWebServiceCall()}
       
       
        <b>#{fooBean.responseToUser}</b>
        
    </h:body>
</html>

Comment: Okay, I found the problem to the error message.  Thanks to all of your suggestions.  My class was spelled FooBean but my @Named(value=fooBean).  That triggered an error.  After changing the case to match, the original error went away.  Now I have a new error "WELD-000321 No conversation found to restore for id YQa==" which is one of my parameters in my query string, i.e., id=YQ==.

Comment: I solved the last issue as well.  Apparently CDI injects a CID parameter into the request object which was in conflict with one of my own parameters.  Thank you all.